# Asking HR about incentives/ stipends

Tags: human-resources, india, bonus

I had gone to other country on business visa for client meeting. All my expenses ( staying ,food and traveling) was being taken care by my client. I had gone for 1 month. I got the usual salary which I get. Now can I ask my HR that I should receive at least some incentives or bonus or something like that other than my salary. Can I ask about this? If yes then how to put it properly in a convincing way.

Comment: If your contract mentions occasionally travel (without mentioning compensation), free travel, food and accommodation **are** the incentives. If it doesn't, and this is something new to an existing job, you can certainly try to negotiate a raise or bonus.

Comment: You can ask but this is something you should have negotiated before.

Comment: @MisterPositive no documents

Comment: So, client paid for all travel and living expenses, and you are basically asking about some additional pay for the added hardship/imposition of being on the road, away from home, in foreign land for an extended (but not really long-term) period of time, in and of itself, right?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere From what I've heard it's incredibly rare in the US but it's pretty much expected as a matter of course in at least a few countries that I knew of in Europe. Typically it's either for the reasons PoloHoleSet gave or it's a way to increase net salary by providing (largely) tax-free bonuses in the form of *per diems*. It's a valid question I think, but YoYo should reword his question to focus on how to word the question professionally.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet  yes you are right

Comment: @JoeStrazzere if you refer to PoloHoleSet comment above you will get an idea what I am trying to say. I don’t know why you finding it so weird. I hope you know that when you work from on-site,you usually get paid more or at least you get some bonus as a token of appreciation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes sure. I am from India.

Answer (score 2):

You can always ask - but I'm not sure what you can expect here.

Typically, at least in the businesses I've worked in, HR is not in charge of handing out extra money randomly to employees just because they traveled.  Finance handles reimbursements for expenses - but what you are saying is you have virtually no expenses, as your client covered them all already.

You could *attempt* to ask for extra money on the basis of the hardship of travel (being away from family) - this would be more applicable as a conversation with your manager, who will know the scope of your job responsibilities.  Beware - if travel is part of the job functions that were originally explained to you as part of your responsibilities, then your manager is likely to assume that it's covered already by your salary.  If this was surprise/emergency travel, then a bonus might be more reasonable, as you have gone above and beyond.

About your only other vector for extra funds would be the case (to your manager, or to finance) that there were costs that were not covered by the client.  For example, they may have paid for food, travel, and hotel... but did they cover wireless?  Or checked luggage?  Or long distance charges to call home?  Or for extra clothes or other things you ended up purchasing if the stay was longer than originally expected.  Expect to be asked for receipts for this stuff.  And the weirder your cost, the more likely you'll need a receipt.  Most likely, if you are in a big company, there's a reimbursement policy that is worth reading first.

**Update from @HLGEM inspired me...**

The time to know whether or not you can request or get extra money is generally BEFORE you travel.  A travel budget for a company is planned anywhere from monthly to yearly.  Often customer-paid trips are planned in an entirely separate place than the company paid trips, and often the company doesn't expect a cross-over between the costs.  In other words, if they had known they had to pay money for the trip, they may never have approved it at all.  You can always ask about *policy* for the future, but you can't reasonably expect money to happen AFTER the travel if you didn't negotiate it in the first place.

The big exception I could think of was cases where the travel was unexpectedly difficult and therefore imposed a hardship you couldn't see coming.  Example - you were asked to do customer travel for a week, but it extended into 3 weeks, causing you to be away much longer than expected and it incurred both cost and inconvenience.  Cases that no one could see coming are fair game for a check-in after the fact.

Comment: "And the weirder your cost, the more likely you'll need a receipt." - makes me think of the Seinfeld episode where Elaine thought her J Peterman expense account was carte blanche.

Comment: And generally, you can not succeed in asking for this after the fact. They budgeted X amount and a surprise request after the trip is not going tot be appreciated. It may be something that would downgrade their opinion of you professionally. If you want something extra for travelling, then you negotiate it before the trip not after.